# how to add elements row and column wise using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe which looks like this:

```
      type   generator  p_nom
0     coal      gen1     12
1     coal      gen2     23
2      gas      gen3     34
3      gas      gen4     45
4  nuclear      gen5     56
5  nuclear      gen6     67
```

I also have one dictionary :

```
dic1 = {
    'coal': ['gen1', 'gen2'],
    'gas': ['gen3', 'gen4'],
    'nuclear': ['gen5', 'gen6']
}
```

which basically you can see combine the `type` and `generator` columns. I want to add the `p_nom` values according to dic1, which means the output should look like this:

```
capacity = {
    'coal': 35,
    'gas': 79,
    'nuclear': 123
}
```

what I did, I added `gen1` and `gen2` for **coal**, `gen3` and `gen4` for **gas** and `gen5` and `gen6` for **nuclear**.
My attempt is:

```
import pandas as pd
dic1 = {
    'coal': ['gen1', 'gen2'],
    'gas': ['gen3', 'gen4'],
    'nuclear': ['gen5', 'gen6']
}
dic3 = {
    'type': ['coal','coal','gas','gas','nuclear','nuclear'],
    'generator': ['gen1','gen2','gen3','gen4','gen5','gen6'],
    'p_nom': [12,23,34,45,56,67]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic3)
capacity = {}
for i in dic1.keys():
    capacity[i] = df.loc[[dic1[i]], ['p_nom']].sum()
print(capacity)
```

But I getting this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([('gen1', 'gen2')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

can someone please help?

Comment: `df.groupby('type')['p_nom'].sum().to_dict()` not sure you even need dic3.

Comment: Hey, thanks man for the help. This one is actually better @Sco